# PHP 7.4 and MIME type of remote files

Tags: php, image, curl, php-7.4

I have a problem with PHP 7.4. Following scenario: I have a file called "image.php" to which a parameter "url" is attached. This will load external images. To be sure it is a PNG, I check the MIME type via curl. With PHP 7.3 (and downwards) it works fine, but PHP 7.4 doesn't return an image, it returns the error message (the('No png file')).

A little part of the code:

```
$cURL = curl_init($_GET['url']);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($cURL);
$curl_info = curl_getinfo($cURL, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
if ($curl_info == 'image/png') die('No png file');
header('Content-type:'.$curl_info);
readfile($_GET['url']);
```

Anyone have an idea why it doesn't work under PHP 7.4?

Comment: I'm curious to know why you're trying to check something that stands to be TRUE and using "No png file" in a `die()`. It probably won't fix this, but it seems to contradict itself.

Comment: There's some code before and after, but this is the "problematic code part" for testing purposes. As I said: Runs under PHP 7.3 and downwards, but not with PHP 7.4... :-/

Comment: What debugging have you done? What is the value of `$curl_info`?

Answer (score 0):

Why `PHP 7.3` works fine? what are you trying to accomplish here ?

If you want to display the image if it's type is `PNG` don't you think you should specify that clearly in your code?

```
$cURL = curl_init($_GET['url']);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($cURL);
$curl_info = curl_getinfo($cURL, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
if ($curl_info == 'image/png') {
    header('Content-type:' . $curl_info);
    readfile($_GET['url']);
} else {
    die('No png file');
}
```

BTW, the above code displays the image perfectly on both `PHP 7.4` and `PHP 7.3` if and only if the image's type is `PNG`